# Disabling particular time in jQuery datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to disable day and time in jQuery datetimepicker? I want to disable a particular time on a particular day(Not the whole day).

Comment: have you looked at the API?

Comment: Also - I see this is your first question. I strongly suggest not telling people to answer - I removed that from your question.

Comment: Are you talking about some plugin or about the build-in one from jQuery UI ?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the suggestions. Yeah, I am talking about jQuery datetimepicker plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Harpreet:
i find a solution for this and it take a lot of time to find it...

if you have a DB, you have to take all the time and hours you have in there.

this is in the Index.php file o where you have the FORM.

```
$db = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i') as date FROM dates";
$result = $app_db->query($db);
```

then convert to  multiarray:

```
$resp = array();
while( $line = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $dateTime = explode(" ", $line["date"]);
  $date = $dateTime[0];
  $time = $dateTime[1];

  if ( !(array_key_exists($date,$resp))) {
      $resp[$date] = [];
      array_push($resp[$date], $time);
  } else {
      array_push($resp[$date], $time);
  };

};
```

then

```
<script>
  let arr = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($resp) ?>' );
</script>
```

NOW go to the principal js file and make it like this:

```
$('#datetime').datetimepicker({
          onGenerate: function(ct,$i){
            let dates = jQuery(this).find('.xdsoft_date '); // this gonna search all the dates charged
            let times = jQuery(this).find('.xdsoft_time '); // and this all the times

            $.each(dates, function(index, value){
              year = jQuery(value).attr('data-year');
              month = jQuery(value).attr('data-month');
              date = jQuery(value).attr('data-date');

              //after search all the dates this gonna add a "0" number if the month is before "10". without this never gonna work.
              month = ++month;
              if (month < 10) {
               month = '0' + month;
              };

              const existDate = arr[year + "/" + month + "/" + date];

              // if the date exist on your DB now check the times in those dates.
              if (existDate){

                //without this class jquery´s gona check all the days again
                jQuery(value).addClass('xdsoft_restricted');

                  $.each(times, function(index){
                    var hour = $(this).attr('data-hour');
                    var minute = $(this).attr('data-minute');

                    if (minute < 10) {
                      minute = minute + '0';
                    }else if (hour < 10) {
                      hour = '0' + hour;
                    };

                    const exisTime = existDate.indexOf(hour+':'+minute);

                    //and finally, if time exist and also the person check that day (xdsoft_current), add disable class.
                    if (exisTime > -1 && $(value).hasClass('xdsoft_current')) {
                      $(this).addClass('xdsoft_disabled');
                    }

                  })
                }
            })
          },
          onSelectDate : function(ct) {
          }
        });
```

this works for me before seeing and try all the solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

Harpreet:

There is an option to enable or disable specific times, called **allowTimes**:

**Example:**

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
 datepicker:false,
 allowTimes:[
  '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', 
  '17:00', '17:05', '17:20', '19:00', '20:00'
 ]
});
```

**Reference:**
http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#allowTimes

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions. However, this does not do what I exactly want to. I want to disable a particular time on a particular day only. For instance, I want to disable time 08/04/2016 1:00 pm but on other dates I want 1 pm to be enabled. More specifically, I want to disable a timestamp. I have tried using allowTimes already but it is not date specific.